# Disabling Sticky Edges on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity, multiple-monitors, mouse, compiz

As the title suggests, I'd like to completely disable Sticky Edges from my set up.

I have disabled the Sticky Edges in the system settings and played around with CCSM and Tweak Tool to change the values of Sticky Edge Velocity, etc. All of this to no avail.

I have three monitors, set up in a triangular fashion (two on top, one on the bottom in the middle). The mouse only seems to stick when moving horizontally between the top two monitors. Moving vertically from bottom to top and vice versa works correctly, requiring almost no velocity/speed/pressure to pass the monitor boundary.

As such, I've attempted to edit the Launcher sticky edge settings, but this is also to no avail.

Thanks for any suggestions!

---

Edit:
After having attempted to set the 'Duration of Sticky Edge Release after Break' to 1 hour, only for it to be capped at 5 seconds, I can confirm that this setting has had no affect either. After having broken through the sticky edge, I cannot return through the edge within the 5 seconds unless I do it with great speed.

It's almost as if Ubuntu is ignoring my settings. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd behaviour that was unexpected and certainly not obvious.

After double checking the Display Settings, it turns out that there was a small gap between my two monitors. This gap essentially meant that moving the mouse slowly did not manage to 'jump' the gap, whereas moving fast enough did.

This issue is separate and distinct from sticky edges. In addition, moving my monitors in the settings to be pushed up against each other results in the desired behaviour of being able to move between monitors at any speed.

Comment: Omg, I was thinking I was going crazy. Thank you. It might help if the window that shows the display arrangement was a bit larger and more obvious. This gap was basically invisible.

Comment: I don't see a gap, and I don't know how to make monitors push up against each other. The cursor still sticks..... If you can tell me how to make them push up against each other that will be great!